# Extracting only some fields from a JSON with Swift

Tags: json, swift, api, codable, decodable

I am sorry, but I am new to Swift programming. I am using [NewsAPI](https://newsapi.org) in my app. Their responses are formatted like this:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "totalResults": 38,
  "articles": [
    {
      "source": {
        "id": "cnn",
        "name": "CNN"
      },
      "author": "Eric Levenson and Lauren del Valle, CNN",
      "title": "Actress Annabella Sciorra is in court at Harvey Weinstein's trial for potential testimony - CNN",
      "description": "Actress Annabella Sciorra is in court for Harvey Weinstein's criminal trial, setting up what could be the first face-to-face testimony from one of the women who has accused him of sexual assault.",
      "url": "https://www.cnn.com/2020/01/23/us/harvey-weinstein-annabella-sciorra/index.html",
      "urlToImage": "https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200123090608-annabella-sciorra-file-super-tease.jpg",
      "publishedAt": "2020-01-23T16:22:00Z",
      "content": "New York (CNN)Actress Annabella Sciorra is in court for Harvey Weinstein's criminal trial, setting up what could be the first face-to-face testimony from one of the women who has accused him of sexual assault.\r\n\"The Sopranos\" actress has said Weinstein raped … [+5398 chars]"
    },
    {
      "source": {
        "id": "ars-technica",
        "name": "Ars Technica"
      },
      "author": "Jennifer Ouellette",
      "title": "Jewel beetle’s bright colored shell serves as camouflage from predators - Ars Technica",
      "description": "University of Bristol scientists offer first real evidence for a 100-year-old theory.",
      "url": "https://arstechnica.com/science/2020/01/study-jewel-beetles-use-iridescence-for-camouflage-not-sexual-selection/",
      "urlToImage": "https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/beetleTOP-760x380.jpg",
      "publishedAt": "2020-01-23T16:00:00Z",
      "content": "Enlarge/ The brightly colored shell of this jewel beetle is a surprisingly effective form of camouflage, according to a new study by scientists at the University of Bristol.\r\n23 with 20 posters participating\r\nArtist and naturalist Abbott Handerson Thayer beca… [+5422 chars]"
    }]
}
```

I have a way of using this data, but it involves too many unnecessary structs/classes. Is there a way for me to decode only the `articles` array from the response into a struct `Article` defined like this:

```
struct Article: Decodable {
    let author: String?
    let title: String?
    let description: String?
    let url: String?
    let urlToImage: String?
    let publishedAt: String?
}
```

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: You can't start wherever you want when decoding, you have to start from the root object but you can ignore any properties you are not interested in and once you have decoded your json you can extract just the array and ignore the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can grab only the part you are interested in.

### 1. Define your model

When defining your model you can declare only the fields you are interested in.

> Since in a comment below you said you only want `author` and `title` for each `Article` I updated the `Article` struct accordingly.

```
struct Response: Decodable {

    let articles: [Article]

    struct Article: Decodable {
        let author: String
        let title: String
    }
}
```

### 2. Decode

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
    let articles = response.articles
    print(articles)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion (and the edit)! The thing is that I don't want to get all the fields from the response. Is there a way for me to get only the title and author?

Comment: @EmanuilGospodinov See my comment to your question for that.

Comment: @EmanuilGospodinov I updated my answer, now you get only `title` and `author`

Comment: This didn't work... Doesn't parse the JSON

Comment: @EmanuilGospodinov What’s the error?

Comment: Never mind, it was my fault. Thank you, this works for me!

Comment: @EmanuilGospodinov Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers